# What is the correct way to Transform JWK to RSA key value Pair

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cryptography, rsa, jwk

let's say we have the following JWK as an embedded resource in the project

[image]

the following code successfully reads the JSON into a JSONWebKey

```
 JsonWebKey jwk = ReadResource();
```

We want this to be transformed into a RSA key value Pair, so we have the following code that is expected to transform the JWK into a RSA KeyPair.

```
            UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();

            RSAParameters publicKey = new RSAParameters();
            RSAParameters privateKey = new RSAParameters();

            JsonWebKey jwk = ReadResource();

           // PUBLIC KEY

            publicKey.Exponent = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.E);
            publicKey.Modulus = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.N);

            // PRIVATE KEY

            privateKey.Exponent = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.E);
            privateKey.Modulus = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.N);
            privateKey.D = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.D);
            privateKey.DP = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.DP);
            privateKey.DQ = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.DQ);
            privateKey.P = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.P);
            privateKey.Q = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.Q);
            privateKey.InverseQ = ByteConverter.GetBytes(jwk.QI);
```

But when we try to Sign the Data as follows

```
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
            RSAalg.ImportParameters(privateKey);
            return RSAalg.SignData(DataToSign, SHA256.Create());
```

it throws CryptographicException @ RSAalg.ImportParameters(privateKey);

what is the correct way to transform a JWK into a RSA Key Pair using C#.net core.

Comment: `UnicdeEncoding` is the wrong kind of encoder. The values are encoded using urlsafe base64 and that is the kind of decoder you need.

Comment: worked like a charm, if you post it as the answer i can mark it as the answer thanks